# How to Deobfuscate a sourcecop protected WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugins, encryption

I have a plugin, which was obfuscated by plugin developer with sourcecop. At some point it began sending out lots of php warnings to debug.log. I couldn't debug it myself since it was obfuscated, but plugin support was also silent. Online Deobfuscateors I tried didn't help. How to Deobfuscate it?

Comment: What are the benefits of using a plugin that goes around the principle of open source? Did you find out after the fact?

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins I don't think there ever were any benefits of it being obfuscated, it's just a plugin that client installed and has been using for a long time, I assume it does it's job well, and maybe there were no alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a single (linux) terminal command to deal with this. Logic is to just change `eval( code_to_eval )` in obfuscated php files to `file_put_contents( __FILE__, code_to_eval )`. At least that worked for me (my problematic plugin was "Wishlist 1Click Registration" by "HappyPlugins"). Here's the command:

```
grep -irl --include \*.php "eval(.*);" . | xargs -i sh -c "echo {}; sed -i 's/eval(\(.*\));/file_put_contents(__FILE__,\1);/g' {}" | xargs -i sh -c "echo {}; php {} > /dev/null || true; sed -i '1s/^?>//g' {}"
```

What the command does:

- gets all .php files in current directory (need to cd to plugin root directory) that contain `eval()` in them,
- replaces all `eval( code )` with `file_put_contents( __FILE__, code )`,
- executes those files with php (need to have `php` available from command line) - this runs all `file_put_contents()` statements and replaces all current obfuscated code in .php file with whatever was passed to `eval()`.
- removes `?>` from beginning of each of those files afterwards - it was used for eval code to work for some reason, but now it would just echo "?>" to browser, which we don't need.

Afterwards, you can also probably delete the "scopbin" folder in plugin's root - it contains one, now unused, .php file.